# Что за ошибка Firefox can't establish a connection to the server?

Tags: websocket

пытаюсь реализовать websocket для этого нашел вот [это](https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket-examples) закачал запускаю получаю такой ответ Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:8004/userId=2651.

```
 ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8004/userId=" + Math.round(Math.random()*1000...
```

вот реализация

$

```
(function(){
                document.cookie = '';
                function wsStart() {
                    ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8004/userId=" + Math.round(Math.random()*10000));
                    ws.onopen = function() { $("#chat").append("<p>система: соединение открыто</p>"); };
                    ws.onclose = function() { $("#chat").append("<p>система: соединение закрыто, пытаюсь переподключиться</p>"); setTimeout(wsStart, 1000);};
                    ws.onmessage = function(evt) { $("#chat").append("<p>"+evt.data+"</p>"); $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);};
                }
                wsStart();
                $('#chat').height($(window).height() - 80);
                $('#input').focus();
```

ругается на эту строку

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8004/userId=" + Math.round(Math.random()*10000));
```

вот [картинка](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dasv7zsqsvnzfo5/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_007.png?dl=0)

Comment: А Вы уверены, что сервер, к которому Вы пытаетесь подключиться, запущен у Вас именно на 8004 порту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта ошибка означает что Firefox не смог установить соединение. Причиной может быть либо то, что вы неверно указали порт, либо запрет на доступ к этому порту.
Соответственно вам нужно проверить что у вас сервер запущен именно на указаном порту и что ваш файрвол не запрещает вам обращаться к этому порту.

Comment: Это в теории. В рельности на адрес в строке типа http://89.1.1.1:8081/ (изменено) приходит ответ и ошибка _"Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 192.168.0.223."_ (сохранено) что более чем странно, особенно, если сказать, что иногда ответы возвращаются нормальные.